# Is it possible to concatenate variable name and string/integer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Within the Javascript or jQuery it is possible to concat strings and variable names like:

```
var id = 5;
$("#wrapper_" + id).hide();
```

With Swift I want to achieve the same, something like:

```
func eventColors (colorID: Int, view: UIView) {
    view.backgroundColor = Constants.Color.eventColor + colorID // Incorrect
}
```

Constants structure:

```
struct Constants {

   struct Color {
      static let eventColor1: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.06, green:0.44, blue:0.64, alpha:1)
      static let eventColor2: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.86, green:0.30, blue:0.99, alpha:1)
      static let eventColor3: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.50, green:0.44, blue:0.64, alpha:1)
   }

}
```

Comment: You need to combine a string and integer right.?

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore Yes, check the constants struct.

Comment: You can combine a string and int like posted in answer.

Comment: No, javascript is an interpreted language (runtime evaluation), Swift is a compiled language (compile time evaluation). Variable names are evaluated at compile time in Swift.

Comment: You’re making a confusion, the snippet you posted doesn’t combine two variables, but creates a string, which jquery interprets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create variable names on the fly in Swift.  You should consider using an array here instead.  Make `eventColor` an array of colors:

```
struct Constants {

    struct Color {
        static let eventColor: [UIColor] = [
            UIColor(red:0.06, green:0.44, blue:0.64, alpha:1),
            UIColor(red:0.86, green:0.30, blue:0.99, alpha:1),
            UIColor(red:0.50, green:0.44, blue:0.64, alpha:1)
        ]
    }

}
```

And then select your color like this:

```
view.backgroundColor = Constants.Color.eventColor[colorID - 1]
```